# Error while getting Values from SSM using Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-parameter-store

While creating Task Definition for fargate I have specified Environment variables to get value from SSM parameter store, but when the task is getting started I'm getting below error

**RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://ssm.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

Taskexecution role have **SSM full access** policy as well as **AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy** policy.
Not sure what I'm missing. Please let me know if I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Tried adding certs to dockerfile, but as its failing before even task starts I don't think issue is with image that was created.

Comment: "certificate signed by unknown authority" is not good. That sounds like some sort of MITM attack, or else Amazon installed a bad SSL certificate on their API. Do you happen to have a VPC Interface Gateway configured for the SSM service? Perhaps that gateway is setup wrong?

Comment: I have VPC interface endpoint setup, but before hitting the actual code I'm getting that error. Does ECS uses VPC endpoint by default if its available ?

Comment: Everything running in your VPC (including ECS) will hit the VPC endpoint by default if it is available.